# Using openModeller plug-in for QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins

As far as I know, niche modeling is possible in the old version of QGIS by using openmedeller plug-in.
I want to use 'openModeller' using the current version of QGIS(v 1.7.4).

Is there any solution to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

A search of the [QGIS Plugins page](https://plugins.qgis.org/search/?q=modeller) shows us that there is no openModeller plug-in for QGIS.  The [openModeller official website](http://openmodeller.sourceforge.net/index.html) also doesn't make any reference to a QGIS plugin